# XSD to C# with custom data types

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have a XSD file, which I need to convert to a C# class. There are few issues though:

**Issue 1:** All the elements are in a Hungarian language (and I don't speak it). What I would like to do, is to translate all the elements (I have translations), so that C# class will make sense to me, but on the output I need to see those original names.

**Question: Can I simply translate all the elements and then simply use Attributes to specify the output name?**.

**Issue 2:** This XSD schema contains custom types. Let me show you an example:

```
        <xs:element name="szlatipus" type="szlatipus_tipus">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>A számla típusa: 1-számla/2-egyszerűsített adattartalmú számla/3-módosító számla/4-érvénytelenítő számla/5-gyűjtőszámla/6-számlával egy tekintet alá eső okirat</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
```

Where in the end of the document, this `szlatipus_tipus` is defined as following:

```
<xs:simpleType name="szlatipus_tipus">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>A számla típusát meghatározó kódszótár.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:enumeration value="1">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>1 - Számla</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="2">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>2 - Egyszerűsített adattartalmú számla</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="3">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>3 - Módosító számla</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="4">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>4 - Érvénytelenítő számla</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="5">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>5 - Gyűjtő számla</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="6">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>6 - Számlával egy tekintet alá eső okirat</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This I believe is causing problems when I tried to use regular Visual Studio dev. prompt `xsd schema /classes`. The output was a complete mess. I have also tried **Liquid XML** yet the result was more or less the same - Mess.

I can surely parse and create class myself, yet I was wondering **if there is a tool, which can generate clean and simple C# class that I can use in my project**?